# Loading a TextureRegion from a Bitmap object in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to load a TextureRegion from a bitmap object that i have

To load the image from file i use :

```
sprite_texture = (TextureRegion) BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(Constants.LevelAtlas,Constants.context, "sprite.png", x, y);
```

But now i want to load the image from a URL. I have opened the URL and created a Bitmap object, i want to know how i could use the Bitmap object to create a sprite texture.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Look at this source: https://github.com/edbartley/AndEngine---Texture-Source-From-Bitmap/blob/master/source.java

I hope this code helps you.